# Django tests failing to install a fixture after adding one more TestCase

Tags: python, django, postgresql, fixtures

I'm almost starting to wonder if there is some limit on how many TestCases a Django app can have, so I need your help to figure out how to avoid this problem and have functional tests in my app with all of the TestCases.

My Django (v1.10.7) app has 4 fixture TestCases, which run fine. As soon as I add a 5th TestCase with fixtures, running the tests 
all together with

*python3 ./manage.py test myapp*

starts resulting in a random one of the old TestCases failing with:

```
ERROR: setUpClass (myapp.tests.RandomOldTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 206, in _cursor
    return self.create_cursor()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 211, in create_cursor
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1019, in setUpClass
    'database': db_name,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 130, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 345, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 64, in handle
    self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 104, in loaddata
    self.load_label(fixture_label)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 167, in load_label
    obj.save(using=self.using)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 201, in save
    models.Model.save_base(self.object, using=using, raw=True, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 824, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 889, in _save_table
    forced_update)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 939, in _do_update
    return filtered._update(values) > 0
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 654, in _update
    return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1148, in execute_sql
    cursor = super(SQLUpdateCompiler, self).execute_sql(result_type)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 833, in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 233, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 206, in _cursor
    return self.create_cursor()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 206, in _cursor
    return self.create_cursor()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 211, in create_cursor
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
django.db.utils.InterfaceError: Problem installing fixture '/home/lynoure/PycharmProjects/usertools2/useraccounts/fixtures/test-fixtures.json': connection already closed
```

It doesn't seem to matter what the new TestCase is, this happens even if I duplicate a pre-existing test with a new name.

In case it matters, this is on Debian Stable, the version of postgresql is 9.6+181, and python3-psycopg2 is 2.6.2-1.

Comment: It seemed tempting to 'solve' this by moving into using a TransactionTestCase for this, but then fixtures didn't get loaded in, so something would still be broken that way.

Comment: serialized_rollback = True  doesn't seem to make any difference either

Comment: --parallel=1 makes no difference either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turned out that if you have couple of

```
super().tearDownClass()
```

missing from your code, this is the kind of symptoms you get. So, if this happens to you, check that your TestCase has the tearDownClass calling the parent.

Comment: Thanks for this, been banging my head for a while against this one. Very unintuitive error, and it also happened to me when moving from N to N+1 tests.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround one can tag some of the TestCases, and then only run tests with the tag excluded:

```
from django.test import tag

@tag('trouble')
class TroubleTestCase(TestCase):
...
```

And to run:

```
python3 ./manage.py test myapp --exclude-tag=trouble
```

One has to run those tests separately afterwards:

```
python3 ./manage.py test myapp --tag=trouble
```